# PHP Check for double in array and delete last one

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filter

I've got a problem by filtering an array!

I want to filter by 'model' name and then delete the last one which is double.

On the image link you can see the array structure.

**First image:**

[image: http://puu.sh/g3ofg/1636c6ff31.png]

In the second image you  can see the double value wich I wan't to filter.

**Second image:**

[image: http://puu.sh/g3oel/27c3825105.png]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood your question.

```
<?php 

$models = [];

// Loop through data
foreach ($records as $key => $value) {

    $model = $value['model'];

    // If it already exists in the array
    if (isset($models["{$model}"])) {
        unset($records["{$key}"]);
    }

    $models["{$model}"] = $model;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the *slow* answer:
Given all your products are in $arrData, and the keys are consecutive

```
foreach($arrData as $key=>$record) {
  for($i=$key+1; $i < count($arrData); $i++) {
    if(isset($arrData[$i]) && $record['model'] == $arrData[$i]['model']) {
      unset($arrData[$i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @thomas-l for the fast answer but with your code I delete both model and not the last one how can I do this?

Comment: My code deletes all but the first record for one model. I tried it online on http://3v4l.org/OUO84 - so perhaps i just misunderstood you